# Query MongoDB for multiple ObjectIDs in Array

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have a collection "users" in my Database. A user can be a member of several teams.

I am using an Array to reference the team IDs.

```
{ _id: ObjectId("552544fd600135861d9e47d5)", 
  name : "User1",
  teams: [
        "5527a9493ebbe2452666c238",
        "5527b1be3371e3a827fa602c"
    ]
}
```

The teams are nothing more than a collection of:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("5527a9493ebbe2452666c238"),
  name: "Team 1"
}
{ _id: ObjectId("5527b1be3371e3a827fa602c"),
  name: "Team 2"
}
```

Now I want to get the names of all the teams in which the user is a member.

I have only found the way of querying it this way:

```
db.teams.find(
   {_id:{$in:
      [ObjectId("5527a9493ebbe2452666c238"),
      ObjectId("5527b1be3371e3a827fa602c")]
   }})
```

To do this, I would need to create an array specifically for this query. I would rather try to avoid this, because I already have the IDs available as an array in the string format. Something like this would be great:

```
db.teams.find(
   {_id:{$in:  
          ["5527a9493ebbe2452666c238",
          "5527b1be3371e3a827fa602c"]  // Strings here, not ObjectIDs
   }})
```

But this does not work. Is there any comfortable way of querying an ObjectID with a set of string IDs?

Thanks & regards
Rolf

Comment: Hi @Rolf can you explain more and I don't know why you check in `teams` collection you simply check `teams` ids presents in `users` collection

Comment: I want to get the names of the teams (and bit more metadata, which is not illustrated here). In the Users collection I have only the TeamIDs available as a reference to the teams collection .

Answer (score 8):

You could use a combination of mongodb's [**`findOne()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) and [**`find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) cursor methods together with the native JavaScript [**`map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to first get the team id's for a specific user (which will be a string array), then use the map function to map the teams' string id's array to an ObjectId's array, and finally query the teams collection with the resulting array as the **`$in`** operator expression:

```
var teams = db.users.findOne({"name": "User1"}).teams;
var obj_ids = teams.map(function (item){ return ObjectId(item)});
db.teams.find({ "_id": { "$in": obj_ids } });
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5527a9493ebbe2452666c238"),
    "name" : "Team 1"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5527b1be3371e3a827fa602c"),
    "name" : "Team 2"
}
```

Comment: That's a nice workaround! Thanks. So far I've iterated through the array "on my own", which is basically just another way to do this. But I was wondering if there is any native MongoDB Feature which can help me with that. 
Maybe my datamodel is just wrong, but I think it made sense to use a referencing model here.