# How to get multiple document using array of MongoDb id?

Tags: mongodb

I have an array of ids and I want to get  all document of them at once. For that I am writing but it return 0 records.

How can I search using multiple Ids ?

```
db.getCollection('feed').find({"_id" : { "$in" : [  
"55880c251df42d0466919268","55bf528e69b70ae79be35006" ]}})
```

I am able to get records by passing single id like

```
db.getCollection('feed').find({"_id":ObjectId("55880c251df42d0466919268")})
```

Comment: You probably need to wrap the ids in `ObjectId()` like you do in the second example.

Comment: ``db.getCollection('feed').find({"_id" : { "$in" : [  
ObjectId("55880c251df42d0466919268"),ObjectId("55bf528e69b70ae79be35006") ]}})`` maybe works.

Comment: Thanks ... It is working

Comment: Pankaj, maybe you did not notice but on top of his comment, @kxxoling posted an answer. It is always good to mark the answer as "accepted" because it helps people having the same problem. They will see the green tick and be more confident it is a working solution. Also it gives a few points to kxxoling ;-)

Comment: How do we wrap individual ids in ObjectId in node?

Comment: This is the best answer I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/29565776/5598574

Answer (score 87):

MongoDB is type sensitive, which means `1` is different with `'1'`, so are `"55880c251df42d0466919268"` and `ObjectId("55880c251df42d0466919268")`. The later one is in ObjectID type but not str, and also is the default `_id` type of MongoDB document.

You can find more information about ObjectID [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).

Just try:

```
db.getCollection('feed').find({"_id" : {"$in" : [ObjectId("55880c251df42d0466919268"), ObjectId("55bf528e69b70ae79be35006")]}});
```

Answer (score 39):

I believe you are missing the `ObjectId`. Try this:

```
db.feed.find({ 
    _id: {
        $in: [ObjectId("55880c251df42d0466919268"), ObjectId("55bf528e69b70ae79be35006")]
    }
});
```

Comment: … or without `ObjectID`: you can still use `$oid` like: `{"_id": {"$in": [{"$oid": "55880c251df42d0466919268"}, {"$oid": "55bf528e69b70ae79be35006"}]}}`

Answer (score 12):

For finding records of multiple documents you have to use "$in" operator
Although your query is fine, you just need to add ObjectId while finding data for Ids

```
db.feed.find({
  "_id" : {
    "$in" : 
      [ObjectId("55880c251df42d0466919268"), 
       ObjectId("55bf528e69b70ae79be35006")
      ]
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi Vikas - your answer appears to be much the same as the two existing answers from kxxoling and Vimalraj Selvam, which both already emphasise that the `ObjectId` part is essential. Is there something extra that you want to contribute?

Comment: @VinceBowdren He provided more readable solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Just I have use it, and is working fine:

```
module.exports.obtenerIncidencias386RangoDias = function (empresas, callback) {
    let arraySuc_Ids = empresas.map((empresa)=>empresa.sucursal_id)
            incidenciasModel.find({'sucursal_id':{$in:arraySuc_Ids}
            }).sort({created_at: 'desc'}).then(
                (resp)=>    {
                    callback(resp)}
            )
};
```

where:

`empresas = ["5ccc642f9e789820146e9cb0","5ccc642f9e789820146e9bb9"]`

Answer (score 1):

The Id's need to be in this format : `ObjectId("id")`.

you can use this to transform your string ID's :

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
```

Answer (score 0):

store array list in var and pass that array list to find function
var list=db.collection_name.find()
db.collection_name.find({_id:{$in:list}})

Answer (score -4):

```
db.getCollection({your_collection_name}).find({
    "_id" : {
    "$in" : 
      [({value1}), 
       ({value2})
      ]
   } 
    })
```