# SQL "IN" equivalent query in Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a facebook like user post database for my app in Firestore.
this is structure

Posts(Collection)

(documents)----(data)

-----post_uid1-{ userId: userId1
                 content: "content1XYZ"}

-----post_uid1-{ userId: userId2
                 content: "content2XYZ"}

and so on.

I want to perform a query to get posts for a user's all friend.

In SQL I could perfom a `SELECT * FROM posts where id in (friendsIds)`.

In Firestore we have(for JAVA) `ref.whereEqualTo("key","value")`

but if a user has let's say 100 friends how will I perform this query?

I know we can chain multiple `whereEqualTo` conditions. but for 100s of values it doesn't seem convenient.

Comment: Chaining `whereEqualTo` calls is the equivalent of an AND operation, so wouldn't work. There is no way to get multiple documents by their IDs in a single call. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip