# Fetch multiple documents by id in Firestore

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently doing a proof of concept for an Android app with the new Firestore as backend/db. I need to fetch a bunch of documents by their id (they are all in the same collection)

Right now, I'm looping thru the id list and fetching them one by one and storing them in a list which in turn updates a RecycleView in the app. This seems to be a lot of work and it does not perform very well.

What is the correct way to fetch a list of documents from Firestore without having to loop all the ids and getting them one by one?

Right now my code looks like this

```
   for (id in ids) {
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("test_collection").whereEqualTo(FieldPath.documentId(), id)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        val res = it.result.map { it.toObject(Test::class.java) }.firstOrNull()

                        if (res != null) {
                            testList.add(res)
                            notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", it.exception)
                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: have you found the answer yet??

Comment: Well.. for now the answer is that it's not possible (at least yet). The good news is that a lot of roundtrips does not necessarily add a lot of overhead...

Comment: yeah thanks i have implemented it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firestore does not currently support query by IDs.

According to [AngularFirebase](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/advanced-firestore-nosql-data-structure-examples/), this is in the roadmap for development in the future, but its not official:

> Keep in mind, Firestore is still in beta. Firebase engineers hinted at some really cool features on the roadmap (geo queries, query by array of ids) - I’ll be sure to keep you posted :)

Comment: I've defended Firestore every time somebody complained about a feature not yet existing but this is ridiculous. A database that doesn't let you get entries by their unique identifiers? Has Google lost their minds? Firestore beta is kind of looking like a joke.

Answer (score 7):

This is the way i'm using until they will add this option

I made that with AngularFire2 but also with the rxfire libary is the same if you are using react or vue.
You can map the null items before subscribing if there are some documents that deleted.

```
const col = this.fire.db.collection('TestCol');
const ids = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'];

const queries = ids.map(el => col.doc(el).valueChanges());
const combo = combineLatest(...queries)
      .subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: This is a great solution in the absence of a direct query by ID

Comment: combineLatest has been deprecated. Any new solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can get specific documents,
here is a sample code:

```
List<String> documentsIds = {your document ids};

FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("collection_name")
.whereIn(FieldPath.documentId(), documentsIds).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                     for (DocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                        YourClass object = document.toObject(YourClass.class);
                        // add to your custom list
                    }   
                }
                
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```