# How can I join data with React native and a many to many firebase firestore collection relationship?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to react native and firebase but understand SQL relationships. I am trying to understand how to model many to many relationships with firebase in NoSQL.

In my scenario, users can own multiple groups and groups can have multiple user owners.

I want to display group information (name, city state) for a particular user. (In this case, doc id: WQQZ6pcMMgQoTxH9cr2XGaPOq9W2).

This is how data is structured in the firebase filestore:

```
{
    "__collections__": {
        "Group": {
            "group3": {
                "city": "Aurora",
                "state": "CO",
                "name": "Group Three",
                "__collections__": {}
            },
            "group4": {
                "state": "CO",
                "name": "Group Four",
                "city": "Denver",
                "__collections__": {}
            },
            "group5": {
                "city": "Aurora",
                "state": "CO",
                "name": "Group Five",
                "__collections__": {}
            }
        },
        "User": {
            "Hm56Zhn9TJP9jVYrzJRqHAB8T8H3": {
                "last_name": "Sneed",
                "first_name": "Sam",
                "__collections__": {}
            },
            "WQQZ6pcMMgQoTxH9cr2XGaPOq9W2": {
                "last_name": "Smith",
                "first_name": "Will",
                "__collections__": {}
            }
        },
        "UserGroups": {
            "F4GubhZKqWcJnHahL0TQTOP62Jj1": {
                "group3": true,
                "group4": true,
                "__collections__": {}
            },
            "WQQZ6pcMMgQoTxH9cr2XGaPOq9W2": {
                "group5": true
                "__collections__": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
export default class GroupSelect extends Component {
    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.userGroupRef = firebase.firestore().collection("UserGroups").doc('WQQZ6pcMMgQoTxH9cr2XGaPOq9W2');

        this.state = {
            userGroups: [
                {
                    uid: 'group1',
                    name: 'Group One',
                    city: 'Chicago',
                    state: 'IL'
                },
                {
                    uid: 'group2',
                    name: 'Group Two',
                    city: 'Denver',
                    state: 'CO'
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        this.userGroupRef.get().then((doc) => {

            var obj = doc._data;

            var group_ids = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
                return key;
            });

            var groups = [];

            var group = {};

            group_ids.forEach(function (group_id) {

                console.log(group_id);

                this.groupRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Group').doc(group_id);
                this.groupRef.get().then((groupDoc) => {
                    group.name = groupDoc._data['name'];
                    group.city = groupDoc._data['city'];
                    group.state = groupDoc._data['state'];
                    groups.push(group);
                });

            });

            console.log(groups); //not populated correctly

            // this.setState({
            //     userGroups: groups
            // });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.state.userGroups.map((userGroup, index) => (
                <Text>{userGroup.name} - {userGroup.city}, {userGroup.state}</Text>
            ))
        )
    }
}
```

If I comment out everything in ComponentDidMount(), the render() shows the original contents of state.UserGroups correctly. But, when I try to populate the array in the ComponentDidMount() and reset the state userGroups var, there is a problem with the join and the timing of the population of the array.

How best to do this?

I am patterning this off of how firebase joins are described here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Idu9EJPSxiY

[image: Users, eventAttendees and Events many-to-many join in firebase realtime db]
<sup>Users, eventAttendees and Events many-to-many join in firebase realtime db</sup>

But, this uses the realtime database instead of filestore, which is what I want to use.

I want to do the same but with: Users, UserGroups, and Groups

Should the data be structured differently?

---

**I implemented Frank van Puffelen's answer below.** 
**It works but that brings up other questions.**

If I use the UserGroups collection as described...

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.userGroupRef = firebase.firestore().collection("UserGroups").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);

    this.state = {
        userGroups: []
    }
}
```

...it works, but see possible "issues" below.

```
componentDidMount() {

    this.userGroupRef.get().then((doc) => {

        var obj = doc._data;

        //get array of group ids
        var group_ids = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
            return key;
        });

        let promises = [];

        //issue: making singleton database calls for each group id, maybe not good.
        group_ids.forEach(function (group_id) { 
            promises.push(firebase.firestore().collection('Group').doc(group_id).get())
        });

        let groups = [];

        let parentThis = this; //issue: get ref to parent this to set in Promise.all below, kinda weird, maybe not so clear

        Promise.all(promises).then(function(docs) {

            docs.forEach((groupDoc) => {
                let group = {};
                group.name = groupDoc._data['name'];
                group.city = groupDoc._data['city'];
                group.state = groupDoc._data['state'];
                groups.push(group);
            });

            parentThis.setState({
                userGroups: groups
            });
        });
    });
}
```

If I restructure data and add a groups collection below User...

```
"User": {
    "WQQZ6pcMMgQoTxH9cr2XGaPOq9W2": {
        "last_name": "Carter",
        "first_name": "Will",
        "__collections__": {
            "Groups": {
                "group1": {
                    "city": "Chicago",
                    "state": "IL",
                    "name": "Group One",
                    "__collections__": {}
                },
                "group2": {
                    "city": "Denver",
                    "state": "CO",
                    "name": "Group Two",
                    "__collections__": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, code becomes more straightforward.

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    //path: User/WQQZ6pcMMgQoTxH9cr2XGaPOq9W2/Groups 
    this.userGroupRef = firebase.firestore().collection("User").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection("Groups");

    this.state = {
        userGroups: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {

    this.userGroupRef.get().then((doc) => {

        let groups = [];

        doc._docs.forEach(function (groupDoc) {
            let group = {};
            group.name = groupDoc._data['name'];
            group.city = groupDoc._data['city'];
            group.state = groupDoc._data['state'];
            groups.push(group);
        });

        this.setState({
            userGroups: groups
        });

    });

}
```

This method seems cleaner to me. But now I have duplicate data in a root Group collection and under User collection.

Is it better to do it in this method with duplicate Group data in the db?

I have a relational db background and learning NoSQL best practices. My instinct is not to duplicate data in the db.

Comment: You're showing a JSON data structure, which typically indicates that you're using the Firebase Realtime Database. But then the code you pasted shows trying to access the data in Cloud Firestore, and the screenshot of code again shows it being accessed in the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and the API of one can't be applied to the other. Please update your question to use only one of these databases.

Comment: I am using the Cloud Filestore. I wrote out the structure of the data in json format so that my collections could be understood. I did not mean to imply that this was using the realtime database.
The code screenshot is from the youtube video link where it discusses many to many joins using the realtime database. I want to do the same but with collections in Cloud Filestore.

Comment: For clarity and to not confuse this question with the realtime database, I updated data dump above using this npm package: node-firestore-import-export.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I implemented your solution, but now I have additional questions. (see edit above after the horizontal rule).

Comment: This video answers my question I believe. I should duplicate the needed group data under the user and not do the joining bit in the client. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ

Comment: Good to hear! Feel free to post your final data structure and code as an answer. Self-answers are encouraged on Stack Overflow, since what worked for you may be helpful for others.

Answer (score 2):

You're printing `console.log(groups)` **outside** of the callback where the groups get loaded. That won't work, as data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously, and your log statement runs before any data is loaded.

This is easiest to see if you place a few simple log statements:

```
console.log("Start loading documents");
group_ids.forEach(function (group_id) {
    this.groupRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Group').doc(group_id);
    this.groupRef.get().then((groupDoc) => {
      console.log("Loaded document");
    });
});
console.log("Started loading documents");
```

When you run this code, it outputs:

> Start loading documents
>
> Started loading documents
>
> Loaded document
>
> Loaded document
>
> ...

This is probably not the order that you expected, but it perfectly explains why the `groups` array is empty when you print it: none of the groups has been loaded yet. In fact, if you log `groups` insode the `then()` callback, you'll see it getting populated one document at a time.

Any code that needs the documents, needs to either be inside the callback, or wait for the document(s) to be loaded by using a promise. Since you're waiting for multiple documents, use  `Promise.all()`:

```
var promises = [];
group_ids.forEach(function (group_id) {
    promises.push(firebase.firestore().collection('Group').doc(group_id).get())
});
Promise.all(promises).then(function(docs) {
    docs.forEach((groupDoc) => {
        group.name = groupDoc._data['name'];
        group.city = groupDoc._data['city'];
        group.state = groupDoc._data['state'];
        groups.push(group);
    });
    console.log(groups);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This video may answer my question.
... at 13:31: "this would probably be duplicate data that would live both in the top-level user object and in this individual review and we'll talk in future videos about the best strategies to keep these kinds of things consistent."

This leads me to believe that I should duplicate the needed group data under the user and not do the joining bit in the client. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ

**Or, maybe not:**
From this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jm66TSlVtcc

[image]

... at 7:17 "If you have a sql background, this is very similar to using an intermediate table for joins"

More details here: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-nosql-data-modeling-by-example/#Subcollection-Many-to-Many-Relationships

In the structure above, how would you get all the tweets that a user has liked(hearted) using the hearts table that has the foreign keys with a single query?

Comment: hmm, maybe same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947659/how-to-join-multiple-documents-in-a-cloud-firestore-query