# How to avoid running out of memory when iterating over multiple ArrayLists?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jvm

I have a code that looks like this.

```
List<Long> eventIds = ... // just arraylist of ids
Iterable<List<Long>> partitions = Iterables.partition(eventIds, 10); // eventIds are partitioned into smaller chunks so one call to database would require less resurces 
Map<Integer, YearlyStatistics> yearlyStatisticsMap = new HashMap<>();
for (List<Long> partition : partitions) {
    List<Event> events = database.getEvents(partition); // This is where I get OutOfMemoryException after couple of loops. It looks like previous list of events is never garbage collected.
    populateStatistics(events, yearlyStatisticsMap);
}
```

One `Event` is never larger than 1MB. JVM has 250MB of memory to work with.
Reason for partitioning the `eventIds` is that I will definitely run out of memory if I try to fetch every object at once from the database. So I thought that I will ask data in smaller chunks and JVM will clear up memory after every loop after `populateStatistics` method is called. Looks like this is not the case as at around ~50th loop OutOfMemoryException is thrown. Is there any way to optimize this code so memory from previous events is freed up?

Comment: Which is the database ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun database is Firestore

Comment: Is it possible in `Firestore` to have an equivalent to IN clause in `SQL` ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help :

Instead of do a call to `event` from database for each partition in a loop, you can do an unique call to the database to retrieve all the events by a list of partitions, example :

```java
List<Long> eventIds = ... // just arraylist of ids
Iterable<List<Long>> partitions = Iterables.partition(eventIds, 10); // eventIds are partitioned into smaller chunks so one call to database would require less resurces 
Map<Integer, YearlyStatistics> yearlyStatisticsMap = new HashMap<>();

// Use a IN with the list of partition on your query
// This structure contains the list of events per partition
Map<Long, List<Event> eventsWithPartitions = database.getEvents(partitions)

// Apply the rest of logic based on the MapeventsWithPartitions
// for eventsWithPartitions
```

The advantage with this solution, we are doing only one network call to the database.

According to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028440/how-to-accomplish-where-in-query-in-cloud-firestore), `Firstore` supports `IN` in queries.

Comment: I don't think the database is the problem. I could easily fetch all Events from database but then I would definitely run out of memory instantly. That's why I process Events in chunks. The problem seems to be that previous chunks don't free up memory when they are discarder, or in this case overwritten.