# Query firestore by a list of document keys

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, geofire

I'm using geofire to store users by their location. As geofire works, I will query by location, and get a list of keys (which in my case are user keys) that suit my location query.

Now I want to get data for all these ID's (which are actually firestore docs) from firestore. Any way I can do this?

I would imagine something like `usersRef.where(key, "in", [array of keys from geofire])`

Comment: There is no Firestore equivalent on a SQL `SELECT * FROM docs WHERE id IN (1,2,3)`. See Sam's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46773341/209103

Comment: Im having a similar requirement. How did you solve this?

Comment: Firestore now supports "IN" queries: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html