# How to get a list of documents based on an array of document ids?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

What's the best way to get a list of documents based on another list of document ids?

If I have `User` and `Profile` objects.

Users have a single Profile
Users can save other users' profiles
The same profile can't be saved twice

The documents of the savedProfile sub collection are stored based on the uid of the user it belongs to. It also has an attribute of `userRef` which stores the uid of the user again. Given that savedProfiles is a list of uids. Is there a way to get a list of profiles based on the savedProfiles subcollection? Currently I am able to make a get request for a users saved profiles which returns a list of uids which I store in a variable. I'm just wondering how I would make the next request to get the full profiles of the savedProfiles based on that list? Saving the whole user profile in a users savedProfiles is also not an option since these profiles can be updated and changed quite frequently and it would be expensive to find and change each users saved profiles if that profile has been saved. (If there was 100,000 users with an average of around 10 saved profiles each).

Please tell me if there's a way to make this sort of query or if there's a better way to structure my data. Thanks.

Comment: There is no specific API for getting a list of document by their IDs. See Sam's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46773341

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Firestore - how to get document by multiple ids in one round trip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I think I managed to find a way. From my cloud function I used `admin.firestore().getAll(refList)`. refList is an array of document references that I want. This returns a promise which gives a list of documents matching those references. The data for each document is accessible like normal with `doc.data()` I've either solved the problem, or I'm doing something very wrong. Feel free to comment and let me know if what I'm doing is okay. Thanks

Comment: Yeah this would be one solution, only thing that sucks about this is that it has to be done from a cloud function, not from a client .. ughhhh