# FireStore Where In Query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there away to perform a `select * from foo where bar in ('a', 'b', 'c')` query in Firebase FireStore?

I have a list of external ID's and I would like to find the documents and internal ID's for this list.

Comment: There is no support for such query in Firestore at the moment. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46773341/209103