# Firestore - how to do a "reverse" array-contains?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection users in firestore where one of the fields is "contact_person".

Then I have an array arrNames {'Jim', 'Danny', 'Rachel'} in my frontend and I want to get all users that have either of these names in their  "contact_person" field.
Something like **where("contact_person" IN arrNames)**

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible (from 11/2019) https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html but keep in mind that the array size can't be greater than 10.

db.collection("projects").where("status", "in", ["public", "unlisted", "secret"]);

Comment: Thank u for the update. Will subscribe to this blog so I can stay in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

This is currently not possible within the Firestore API. You will need to do a separate get for each document, unless the names happen to be in a single contiguous range.

Also see:

- [FireStore Where In Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507271/firestore-where-in-query?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Google Firestore - how to get document by multiple ids in one round trip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip)