# How to filter collections in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have below FireStore data

[image]

And I have a list `specialUsers` which is defined as

```
val specialUsers = arrayOf("stark@gmail.com", "lannester@gmail.com")
```

So I want to get collections which are in the `specialUsers`, something like

```
collection("users").whereIn(specialUsers)
```

But, couldn't find any documentation related to this. How can I perform above intention in Firestore?

Comment: The client-side SDKs for Cloud Firestore don't support this type of query yet. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip

Answer (score 1):

As he says [here](https://youtu.be/v_hR4K4auoQ?t=378) in 6:19

> There is still no way for the database to automatically grab specific user name and profile for  each review as I requesting them.  I would need to make separate database request for every single review I get to fetch this information  and that's bad. so If we wont to automatically include information about who rote a particular review we will need to copy sample of the user profile to the particular review and this is the way (to brake data Normalization) specifically in could FireStore.

Comment: You are right but what would happen if the user changes his original data (e.g- name). It does not change the data in the review document. Did you find anything about this issue?