# In cloud firestore is it possible to query multiple documents from the same collection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I am working with react-native and cloud firestore and I wanted to check if it is possible to obtain multiple documents from a collection by making a single query...

Comment: [Have you tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip)?