# How to get multiple documents from same collection using "Firestore" Pipeline request?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, pipeline

I have an array of users IDs under my current user object..i want to get all those members from my "members" collection whose IDs is in my array.

1. Is there any way to query specific documents with specific IDs (more then one IDs)?
2. Is firestore pipeline request can handle this case, if yes then how ?
3. Is this approach is good if use pipeline technique?

Comment: In the client-side SDKs for Firestore there is no way to retrieve multiple documents by their Id with a single call. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so pipelining all  document request is the only solution for this?

Comment: With the Android SDK that is indeed the way to go. It's quite common, and not nearly as slow as you may think when applied to a number of documents that you'd reasonably expect to process in a mobile app. For server-side, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48423626.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen pipelining is really fast i just implemented it.