# Firebase Query, how use whereEqualTo for a list of possible values

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello i have problem with use whereEqualTo for a list of possible values

My goal is make something like this

```
query
    .orderBy("dateTime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .limit(LOAD_COUNT)
    .whereEqualTo("tittle","new advert for search2")
    .whereEqualTo("tittle","new advert for search1")
    .get()
```

or

```
query
    .orderBy("dateTime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .limit(LOAD_COUNT)
    .whereEqualTo("tittle","new advert for search2" || "new advert for search1")
    .get()
```

structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLVym.png)
screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGOLp.png)
with datetime
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZG3u.png)

or merge few querying to one to get one list with results

but i could not find any solutions  for resolving this problem

I hope that someone know best way for resolve this issue

Comment: This is actually possible. Please add your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo added structure https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLVym.png

Comment: Please add it as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGOLp.png this is good?

Comment: I cannot see any `dateTime` property in your document.

Comment: @AlexMamo with dateTime https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZG3u.png

Comment: To do this type of "WHERE field IN (value1, value2)" query on Firestore for the moment. You will have to do a separate query for each value, and merge the results client-side. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip and https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/321

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar by using this adapter: [RecyclerViewMergedAdapter](https://github.com/martijnvdwoude/recycler-view-merge-adapter)

Define 2 different queries and set it to 2 different adapters (in my example below, its `mAdapter` and `mAdapter2`). And then merge the adapters this way:

```
RecyclerViewMergeAdapter recyclerViewMergeAdapter = new RecyclerViewMergeAdapter();
mOrdersRecycler.setAdapter(recyclerViewMergeAdapter);
recyclerViewMergeAdapter.addAdapter(mAdapter);
recyclerViewMergeAdapter.addAdapter(mAdapter2);

//set recyclerview adapter to newly mergeadapter
mOrdersRecycler.setAdapter(recyclerViewMergeAdapter);
```

Comment: thx how i see it is sole way to make what i need