# Firebase: Populate a search with data from another collection

Tags: firebase, react-native, search, google-cloud-firestore, populate

I have two collecitons:  users and establishments, in the user collection i save the respective establishment id. I would like to know how to bring back the establishment data when i request the users.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore operations always read data from a single collection. They have no concept like SQL's server-side JOIN. If you want to load the establishments, you will have to do so with an additional call, possibly a [separate call for each of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip).