# Firestore query two collections

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am using a firebase cloudstore. I know that there are no joins available. But I can't even find a way to query data efficiently by making two separate queries.

I have two collections

- users

  - fullname
  - avatar
- posts

  - text
  - postOwner (userId)

I want to query for **posts** get all users ids and then query **users** collection for additional information. But it seems that there is no way to load data in bulk given list of ids. (react-native-firebase)

1. How can I do that?
2. Do you think this data model well structured? Any alternatives?

If there is no way please recommend a workaround.

Comment: There is no Firestore equivalent of a SQL `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id IN (1,2,3)` in the client-side SDKs. You will need to load them individually, but this is not nearly as slow as you may think (for reasonable numbers of documents for handling in a client-side app). This has been asked before, so have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/46721517,

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ok, I didn't try if it will cause a performance issue, I will give it a go. However, we will pay more for reading data N times. I will give it a go anyway. Thanks

Comment: On reading Firestore charging per document that is read. It doesn't matter if you read them individually, or through a query, the charges are the same.