# Use firestore in keyword to get documents by uids

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip) that it is possible to use the `in` keyword to query firestore, where the **fields** of a document are matched. I want to match the **uids** of the documents in my collection. Is it possible to get documents having certain uids only?

I have tried `.where('id', 'in', idsArray)` and `.where('uid', 'in', idsArray)` (only certain doc uids stored in idsArray) with no avail. Please help.

Comment: So you have an array of uids and you want to query all the docs corresponding to these uid values. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Precisely so.

Comment: What is the data structure you have? Something like { id: string, uuid: string, ....}?

Comment: @carlosvin which data structure? in my array or in firestore?

Comment: @VaibhavJoshi in firestore

Comment: I'm not storing uid in the document. My datastructure is something like {user_name:string, user_email:string, ...}

Comment: Please include structures in your question because it's easier to read and adds clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, based on an array of uids, to query all the docs corresponding to these uid values, you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
const uids = ['abcde...', 'klmno...', 'wxyz...'];

const promises = uids.map(u => db.collection("yourcollection").doc(u).get());

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {

    //results is an array of DocumentSnapshots
    //use anny array method, like map or forEach      

    results.map(docSnapshot => {
            console.log(docSnapshot.data());
    });
});
```

Comment: So if I have 5 uids in my array, won't it make 5 different get requests?

Comment: Yes, but they will be done in parallel with `Promise.all()`. In terms of cost it will be the same cost than a query that returns 5 documents. If, for a specific reason, you absolutely need to use a query, you would need to add an extra field in your documents which holds the document's uid.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says that you can't use more than 10 identifiers.

> Use the in operator to combine **up to 10 equality (==)** clauses on the same field with a logical OR. An in query returns documents where the given field matches any of the comparison values.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any

Other way to access to a document by identifier is:

```
db.collection('users').doc(uid);
```

Comment: My array contains only 3-4 values.