# get more than 10 documents from firestore in one round trip using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently using `whereIn` for this. But only get 10 or less douments at once. **whereIn 10 entries or less according to the firestore documentation**

Is there any way to get more than 10 documents at once in one round trip?

```
 return _db
        .collection('books')
        .where('docId', whereIn: ['id1', 'id2'...'id10'])
        .get()
        .then((value) => value.docs.map((e) => BookModel.fromFireStore(e)).toList());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, 10 is a hard limit and can't be exceeded.  You will need to perform multiple queries to get more than 10 documents by ID. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) states:

> Use the `in` operator to combine up to 10 equality (==) clauses on the same field with a logical OR.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered. Here I just want to show how you can get those documents with multiple round-trips cause it is not an easy task as well. It took me some time to implement this, so I hope it will save someone else's time.

First create a function for one round-trip:

```dart
Future<List<Book>> _getBooksByIds(ids) {
  return _instance
      .collection('books')
      .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: ids)
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) => BookModel.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList();
  });
}
```

Then split by 10 your ids

```dart
ids = ['id1', 'id2'...'id11'];
final idsBy10 = [
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i += 10)
    ids.sublist(i, min(i + 10, ids.length))
];
```

Then run multiple requests and merge their results:

```dart
Future.wait<List<Book>>(idsBy10.map((ids) => _getBooksByIds(ids)))
        .then((listOfLists) => listOfLists.expand((l) => l).toList());
```