# Query Firestore Rest API by multiple document ids

Tags: rest, google-cloud-firestore

I have noticed that documents that are returned by the API / runQuery do contain the document name, but I can't find any information within the structuredQuery docs how to query by multiple ids.

```
{
  document: {
    name: 'projects/:projectId/databases/(default)/documents/collection/id',
    fields: ...,
    createTime: '2021-01-16T13:35:02.151442Z',
    updateTime: '2021-01-18T10:42:32.257199Z'
  },
  readTime: '2021-01-18T17:10:33.600112Z'
},
```

Firestore does support a whereIn query by document id `Collection.where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', ["123","456","789"])`, so I thought the Rest API might support is as well.

Do I miss something, or does `runQuery` not support queryById functionality?

Comment: take a look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by calling [batchGet](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/batchGet) endpoint:

`https://content-firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/databases/(default)/documents:batchGet`

with the following JSON on the request body.

```
{
  "documents": [
    "projects/<PROJECT_ID>/databases/(default)/documents/<COLLECTION_ID>/<DOC_ID1>",
    "projects/<PROJECT_ID>/databases/(default)/documents/<COLLECTION_ID>/<DOC_ID2>",
    "projects/<PROJECT_ID>/databases/(default)/documents/<COLLECTION_ID>/<DOC_ID3>",
  ]
}
```