# Fetching multiple data in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is the layout of my firebase database.

```
MyCollection > MyDocument1 > 1: Data1
                           > 2: Data2
                           > 3: Data3
                           > 4: Data4
                           > 5: Data5
             > MyDocument2
             > MyDocument3
```

I'm trying to do the multiple fetch but having a difficulty in implementing it. What am I missing?

```
final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshot = await db.collection('MyCollection').where('MyDocument1', 'in',['1','2','3']).get();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query you execute:

```
db.collection('MyCollection').where('MyDocument1', 'in',['1','2','3'])
```

In here you are looking for a field `MyDocument1` in each document in `MyCollection` and then check whether its value is `'1'`,`'2'` or `'3'`.

Is that indeed what you want to do? If so, can you show a screenshot from the Firebase console of a document you expect to be returned?

---

If you just want to read `MyDocument1` that'd be:

```
db.collection('MyCollection').doc('MyDocument1')
```

Comment: Ohh, then I'm wrong. `MyDocument1` is the document name. The fields of the documents are `'1','2','3'`. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you expect the code to do? If you want to just read that one document, check the update in my answer,.

Comment: What I wanted to do is fetch let's say 1,2,3. Or maybe 2,3. Or 1,3. But all of those are in the fields.
But actually now that you mention, I think my layout is wrong. My fields will have a thousand of fields which I think may exceed the limit per Collection. I think, my fields should be the collection, and fetch multiple collection.

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-several-documents-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-tri
I think this is what I need. Thanks for your help, I noticed now what is my mistake.