# Does firebase query support 'in' operator on documentId against a list?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
const q = query(collection(db, "products"), where(documentId(), 'in', listOfIds))
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
```

I am trying to do a query in a collection where their documentId exists in a list of ids, but I got an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid query. When querying with documentId(), you must provide a valid string or a DocumentReference, but it was: a custom rf object.

not sure if it's relevant, but my firebase-admin version is 11.8.0

If querying documentId in a list is not supported, what's the best workaround to filter documents in a collection where their documentId exists in another collection?

Comment: Fetch each document individually while iterating the list.

Comment: On the Node.js Admin SDK you might want to try `getAll` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53508963/209103

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid query. When querying with documentId(), you must provide a valid string or a DocumentReference, but it was: a custom rf object.

Because the `listOfIds` object is not a `string`, nor a `DocumentReference` object, as the function requires. The `in` operator lets you combine multiple equality (==) clauses on the same **field** with a logical OR, not a document ID. So what you're trying is currently not possible.

What you can do is save the document ID as a field inside the document, and then use the [`in` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any).

Or as @DougStevenson mentioned in his comment, you can fetch each document individually while you iterate the list.

Comment: Hey Derek. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?