# Pymongo - find multiple different documents

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

my question is very similar to [how-to-get-multiple-document-using-array-of-mongodb-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264225/how-to-get-multiple-document-using-array-of-mongodb-id), however, **I would like to find multiple documents without using the `_id`**.

That is, consider that I have documents such as 
the

```
document = { _id: _id, key_1: val_1, key_2: val_2, key_3: val_3}
```

**I need to be able to .find() by multiple parameters**, as for example,

```
query_1 = {key_1: foo, key_2: bar}
query_2 = {key_1: foofoo, key_2: barbar}
```

Right now, I am running a query for `query_1`, followed by a query for `query_2`.

As it turns out, this method is extremely inefficient.
I tried to add concurrency as to make it faster, but the speedup was not even 2x.

**Is it possible to query multiple documents at once?**,
I am looking for a method that returns the union of the matches for query_1 AND query_2.
If this is not possible, do you have any suggestions that might speed a query of this type?

Thank you for your help.